# Server not listening to all IP addresses

Tags: postgresql, postico

I have deployed my website using DigitalOcean and now I want to access the Postgres database of that website using Postico. When I try to connect my Postgres database to Postico the following error appears:

```
could not connect to server: Operation timed out
    Is the server running on host "165.22.216.110" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

This is a part of /etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf file:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONNECTIONS AND AUTHENTICATION
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'          # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                        # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                        # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                                        # (change requires restart)
port = 5432                             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100                   # (change requires restart)
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3     # (change requires restart)
unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql' # comma-separated list of directories
                                        # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_group = ''                 # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_permissions = 0777         # begin with 0 to use octal notation
                                        # (change requires restart)
#bonjour = off                          # advertise server via Bonjour
                                        # (change requires restart)
#bonjour_name = ''                      # defaults to the computer name
                                        # (change requires restart)

# - Security and Authentication -

#authentication_timeout = 1min          # 1s-600s
ssl = on
#ssl_ciphers = 'HIGH:MEDIUM:+3DES:!aNULL' # allowed SSL ciphers
#ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = on
#ssl_ecdh_curve = 'prime256v1'
#ssl_dh_params_file = ''
ssl_cert_file = '/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem'
ssl_key_file = '/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key'
#ssl_ca_file = ''
#ssl_crl_file = ''
#password_encryption = md5              # md5 or scram-sha-256
#db_user_namespace = off
#row_security = on

# GSSAPI using Kerberos
#krb_server_keyfile = ''
#krb_caseins_users = off

# - TCP Keepalives -
# see "man 7 tcp" for details

#tcp_keepalives_idle = 0                # TCP_KEEPIDLE, in seconds;
                                        # 0 selects the system default
#tcp_keepalives_interval = 0            # TCP_KEEPINTVL, in seconds;
                                        # 0 selects the system default
#tcp_keepalives_count = 0               # TCP_KEEPCNT;
                                        # 0 selects the system default
```

The PostgreSQL-10-main.log also says:

```
2019-08-09 16:29:46.848 UTC [22963] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

I have also reloaded the Postgres server several times

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Firewall on the server?

Comment: You probably need to add the connecting host to the `pg_hba.conf` file in the same directory as the `postgresql.conf` file. It will also require a restart of the postgres service. You can also view a more detailed error on the DB server logs. `/var/log/postgresql/postgres-<version>-main.log`

Comment: Yes a firewall is enabled on the server

Comment: Then turn the firewall off, or add a rule that allows connections to Postgres' port

Comment: Thank you so much @a_horse_with_no_name, because of you now my website is up and running!